# In Java, why is map.get(key)[0] valid as left-hand side, but map.get(key) is not?

Tags: java, dictionary, variable-assignment

Example:

```
Map<Object, String[]> map = new HashMap<Object, String[]>();
Object key = new Object();
map.put(key, new String[2]);

map.get(key)[0] = "test"; // this is valid
map.get(key) = null; // but this is not valid
```

I understand the correct syntax is

```
map.put(key, null);
```

So 2 questions:  why isn't it valid when [] version is, and is there some other markup that would make map.get be assignable?

Comment: Because the left hand side of an assignment expression has to be a variable and `map.get(key)[0]` is a variable.

Answer (score 1):

Since `map.get(key)` is not a valid assignment target, `map.get(key) = null` is invalid. The reason for it is the same as in this simple example:

```
class Demo {
    private String[] array = new String[100];
    public String[] getArray() {
        return array;
    }
}
```

Consider this code that does not compile:

```
Demo demo = new Demo();
String[] replacement = new String[10];
demo.getArray() = replacement; // This line does not compile
```

If the last line were allowed to compile, users of the `Demo` class would be effectively gain control over the private variable `array` inside `Demo` class, even though the class exposes only a getter.

However, `map.get(key)` is a perfectly valid target for the index operator, i.e. `[0]` can be applied.

In turn, index operator returns a valid target for an assignment, so `map.get(key)[0] = "test"` is valid.

Answer (score 1):

Java doesn't let just any expression be on the left hand side of an assignment operator (`=`).  You need more than just a value; you need something to assign whatever is on the right side to it -- a variable.

The [JLS, Section 15.26](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26), goes into what is allowed on the left side to enforce this policy:

> Assignment:
>
> LeftHandSide AssignmentOperator Expression
>
> LeftHandSide:
>
> ExpressionName
>
> FieldAccess
>
> ArrayAccess

Clicking "ExpressionName" yields:

> ExpressionName:
>
> Identifier
>
> AmbiguousName . Identifier
>
> AmbiguousName:
>
> Identifier
>
> AmbiguousName . Identifier

It can be a field access expression, an array access expression, or an identifier.

Your code `map.get(key)[0]` is an array access expression, so it's allowed, but `map.get(key)` is none of the above (a [method invocation expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12)), so it isn't allowed.

Answer (score 0):

`map.get(key)` is never assignable as you can only assign values to variables (or array items when accessed using the index operator `[index]`).

`map.get(key)[0]` is a shorthand for `String something[] = map.get(key); something[0]="test";` (i.e., `map.get(key)`returns a `String`-array and there you can apply the index operator), therefore it works.

Answer (score 0):

Java language specification says that left hand side of assignment expression can be either an expression name, a field access expression or an array access expression. And expression name is (roughly) an identifier.

You can then write things like `i = 3`, `o.f = 3` or `a[4] = 3`.

So a method call expression is not acceptable as the left hand side of an assignment expression, this is why `map.get(key)` is not acceptable.